# get-hotfix on DC's and show DC's that are missing it

Tags: powershell, dns, patch

The powershell script works as is, however; it only shows the DC's that have it installed and does not add the DC's that are missing it (patch). How can I add  the code to add the DC names even if it is missing the patch?

```
 $default_log = $env:userprofile + "\Desktop\report_dc_installed_Hotfixes.csv"
 $KBPatch = Read-Host "Enter the KB Number"
 get-hotfix -id $KBPatch -ComputerName ((get-adforest).globalcatalogs) | `select  @{name='ServerName';expression={$_.CSName}},HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn | `export-csv $default_log -append –NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: How can you do it? Rewrite the code to iterate the list of GC servers and output `$true` if the hotfix is installed or `$false` if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want in your output? The global catalogs. Start there.

What do you want to know about them? Their name, select that. Whether they have the hotfix installed. Select that.

Where do you want it? In your CSV. Put it there.

```
(Get-ADForest).GlobalCatalogs |
     Select-Object @{Name='ServerName';      Expression={$_}},
                   @{Name="HotFixInstalled"; Expression={
                     [bool](Get-HotFix -Id $KBPatch -ComputerName $_ -EA SilentlyContinue)
                   }} |
    Export-Csv -Path $DefaultLog -Append –NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i'd do it [untested]...

```
$default_log = $env:userprofile + "\Desktop\report_dc_installed_Hotfixes.csv"
$KBPatch = Read-Host "Enter the KB Number"

(get-adforest).globalcatalogs | % {
    $hf_installed = $true
    try {
        $hf = get-hotfix -id $KBPatch -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop 
    } catch {
        $hf_installed = $false
    }

    if ($hf_installed) {
        $hf | `select  @{name='ServerName';expression={$_.CSName}},@{name='HotfixInstalled';expression={$hf_installed}},HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn | `export-csv $default_log -append –NoTypeInformation
    } else {
        [pscustomobject] @{
            'ServerName'=$_;
            'HotfixInstalled'=$hf_installed
        } | export-csv $default_log -append –NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

logic explanation:

1. we need to explicitly test each host for success/failure so we loop
   (foreach-object, %)
2. we test for exception which is thrown in the case of the patch not
       existing (try/catch with -erroraction stop on our command)
3. we then check whether success or failure in order to determine the
       type of information to write to the log

..why didn't you just use the force?